# How to store int pointer in void*?

Tags: c, pointers, casting

Scenario is as follows:

```
typedef struct a {
    void* val;
} a_t;

void fun (void** val)
{
    int a = 5;
    *val = &a;
}

a_t *x;
x = malloc (sizeof *x);
fun (&x->val);

printf ("%d", *((int*)(x->val)));
```

I would expect, that the `x->val` is of type `void*` (when used in `printf()`). How can I get back that int value I stored into it?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in `fun`
If you expect 5 on STDOUT than this function should look like this:

```
void fun (void** val)
{
    int *a = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *a = 5;
    *val = a;
}
```

You should not return pointer to automatic variable because it's allocated on stack and deferred after function executions. To get more info look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4824372/1387612)

Comment: If you are OK with the answer, then you should accept it, so your question appears as answered in the feed. :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the pointer is set to a local variable. So when the function terminates, it's memory will be de-allocated, thus the pointer will be set to garbage (it will become a [dangling pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer) as Hans suggested).

So if you are lucky, the `printf()` will print garbage, if not, then it will print 5.

---

A quick fix would be to add the `static` keyword to `int a`, which make it not to be de-allocated when the function gets terminated.

```
void fun(void** val) {
  static int a = 5;
  *val = &a;
}
```

However this is not very flexible, because all the instances of `fun()` will have the same variable `a`.

Or you could dynamically allocate memory like this:

```
void fun(void** val) {
  int *a = malloc(sizeof(int));
  *a = 5;
  *val = a;
}
```

Don't forget to free your memory like this:

```
  a_t *x;
  x = malloc (sizeof *x);
  fun (&x->val);

  printf ("%d", *((int*)(x->val)));
  free(x->val);  // this has to go first
  free(x);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why a -1? I can't see why. I mean my answer even shows how to de-allocate the memory.

Comment: Thanks @janisz , +1 to you too for answering first.