# Function that creates and returns an array is causing problems

Tags: c, arrays, function, variable-length-array

I tried to write a function that returns a random array of pixel colors, so when I call `randomPalette(i)`, the function will create a random array of `i` colors. Below are my codes. It says error at `random[colors]` that expression must have constant value. I don't know why. How to fix it?

```
pixel* randomPalette(int colors){

pixel random[colors] ;
int i, x;
srand(time(NULL)); //generate a random seed
for (i = 0; i < colors; i++){
    x = rand() % 256;
    random[i].r = x; random[i].g = x; random[i].b = x;
}
return random;
}
```

Comment: You can't return a local variable.  Read this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824342/returning-a-local-variable-from-function-in-c

Comment: Aside: You should call `srand` only once at the beginning of your program. The way you re-seed the random number generator here will cause the function to return the same set of pixels if it is called within the same second of system time.

Comment: Also, `srand(time(NULL));` will cause rand() to generate the exact same sequence of "random" numbers if your function is called such that `time(NULL)` returns the same value as the previous invocation.  Man page is here:  http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/time.2.html

Answer (score 6):

In your code, firstly

```
pixel random[colors] ;
```

syntax is called [variable length array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) a.k.a VLA and only supported on and over `C99`. If you want this to work, you need to enforce your compiler to use `C99` mode, like for `gcc`, you'll need to use `--std=C99` compiler option.

Secondly, `random` is an automatic local variable and you're trying to `return` (the address of) it. If the returned value is being used, you'll invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Solution: use a pointer and dynamic memory allocation, like [`malloc()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) and family. Dynamically allocated memory lifetime remains alive until deallocated manually by calling [`free()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/free), so you can return the pointer from the function and use it in the caller, too.

Answer (score 3):

> Below are my codes. It says error at random[colors] that expression
>   must have constant value. I don't know why. How to fix it?

Apparently you don't have support for variable length arrays. Either use a fixed integer (such as `#define` or const integer) below instead of `colors`:

```
pixel random[colors] ;
```

or allocate memory dynamically. e.g.

```
pixel *random = malloc (sizeof(pixel) * colors);
```

But don't forget to `free` if you use approach as above.

---

Finally, you can't do this either:

```
return random;
```

because you are returning address to local variable which will go out of scope when function ends. Actually, you can return `random` if you initialize it using dynamic memory allocation such as with `malloc`. But if you don't use dynamic memory you can't return that.