# Regarding Return Types in C

Tags: c

I'm a beginner in C programming and I've written a tiny block of code as follows:

```
char* aFunction() {
    char aName[100] = "abc";
    printf ("%s", aName);
    return aName;
}


int main (int argc, char** argv) {
  char* w = aFunction();
  printf ("%s", w);
}
```

When I compile and run, I get the output "abc(null)" but I was expecting "abcabc". Could someone explain to me why the w variable prints null? How would I fix this so that I could call printf in main and get "abc"? In other words, what is the proper way to pass the value of aName to the w variable?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824342/returning-a-local-variable-from-function-in-c. Also, always compile with warnings enabled (e.g. `-pedantic -Wall` in case of gcc)

Comment: did your compiler not give you any warnings when you tried to compile?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot return `aName` in your function because it is a local variable that is lost after returning from `aFunction`

One quick way to fix it is to declare `aName` static like so

```
static char aName[100] = "abc";
```

Comment: Perhaps better is `char *aName = "abc";`

Answer (score 1):

When you compile it you will get a warning

```
warning: function returns address of local variable
```

as `aName` is a local variable and its scope is until your function terminates.

What you can do is , declare a `char *` in function , allocate memory to it and then `return` it from your function `aFunction`.

An example -

```
char *aFunction() {
     char *aName;
     aName=malloc(3+1);
     if(aName==NULL)
          return NULL;
     strcpy(aName,"abc");
     printf ("%s", aName);
     return aName;
}


int main (int argc, char** argv) {
    char* w = aFunction();
    if(w!=NULL){
       printf ("%s", w);
       free(w);
    }
}
```

*Note*- Please enable your compiler warnings .