# Changing the value of a pointer passed by reference

Tags: c++, pointers, pass-by-reference

I have this maybe weird question. I was considering following example where I pass a pointer by reference so if I change the pointer address of the argument the initial pointer should also change the address. And indeed this happens.
However the value of a in the main method will have some random value and not 3 as the q variable inside `changePointer` whose address we use to change pointer a to.

Is there something stupid oversee or is the whole thing just undefined behaviour.

```
#include <iostream>

void changePointer(int* &p) {
  int q = 3;
  std::cout << "Address of q: " << &q << std::endl;
  p = &q;
  std::cout << "Value of p: " << *p << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  int* a = new int(4);
  changePointer(a);
  std::cout << "Adress of a: " << a << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Value of a: " << *a << std::endl;

}
```

Comment: `q` is scoped variable, it gets destroyed when `changePointer` returns => `a` then points to freed memory => `a` is invalid pointer => `*a` is Undefined Behavior. Write `delete p; p = new int(3)` and `delete `p` in `main`.

Comment: Ah right, this makes sense. Thanks

Comment: It's also duplicate of [Pointer to local variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570366/pointer-to-local-variable), [returning a local variable from function in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824342/returning-a-local-variable-from-function-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`q` is scoped variable, it gets destroyed when `changePointer` returns. `a` then points to freed memory, so it's invalid pointer, and dereferencing it (`*a`) is Undefined Behavior.

Corrected code:

```
void changePointer(int* &p) {
  int* q = new int(3); // this way q lives until you delete it
  std::cout << "Address of q: " << q << std::endl;
  delete p; // we don't want unfreeable memory
  p = q;
  std::cout << "Value of p: " << *p << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  int* a = new int(4);
  changePointer(a);
  std::cout << "Adress of a: " << a << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Value of a: " << *a << std::endl;
  delete a;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is undefined behavior because you access a local variable which is already vanished.

Try adding `static` before `int q = 3;` and making the variable static so that the variable won't vanish on returning from the function.

Also, please do not cause memory leak by allocating some buffer to `a` and throwing it away!

Answer (score 1):

`q` is a local variable inside `changePointer`, so when `changePointer` exits the address of `q` contains garbage.