# trying to fix bug - segmentation fault 11

Tags: c, debugging, segmentation-fault

I've been given this piece of code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <math.h>

 struct polar_coordinate{
   double theta;
   double r;
 };
 struct polar_coordinate * polar(double x, double y);

int main(void){
   double x = 2.0;
   double y = 3.0;
   struct polar_coordinate * pci;

   pci = polar(x,y);
   printf("The coordinate x = %.1f and y = %.1f is 
   in polar coordinates theta = %.2f and r = %.2f\n ",x,y,pci->theta,pci->r);
   }

struct polar_coordinate * polar(double x, double y){
   struct polar_coordinate pc;
   pc.r = sqrt(x*x + y*y);
   pc.theta = atan2(y,x);
   return &pc;
}
```

I am then told that the struct polar_coordinate * polar function has a bug, that I have to fix. I tried doing this by using:

```
 struct polar_coordinate * polar(double x, double y){
   struct polar_coordinate * pc;
   pc->r = sqrt(x*x + y*y);
   pc->theta = atan2(y,x);
   return pc;
}
```

The code can then compile but if I try to run it I get a segmentation fault 11. But I can't really see what should be wrong.

Comment: `polar()` returns a pointer to a local variable, whose lifetime ends once the function returns. Increase your compiler warnings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [returning a local variable from function in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824342/returning-a-local-variable-from-function-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to return local variable so you are getting error of segmentation fault  so allocate dynamic  memory using `malloc` or `calloc` and `free` after use.

working code with changes....

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

struct polar_coordinate{
    double theta;
    double r;
};
struct polar_coordinate * polar(double x, double y);

int main(void){
    double x = 2.0;
    double y = 3.0;
    struct polar_coordinate * pci;

    pci = polar(x, y);
    printf("The coordinate x = %.1f and y = %.1f is in polar coordinates theta = %.2f and r = %.2f\n ",x,y,pci->theta,pci->r);

    if (pci)
        free(pci);  //free memory after use
}

struct polar_coordinate * polar(double x, double y){
    struct polar_coordinate *pc = malloc(sizeof (struct polar_coordinate)); //Dynamic memory allocation

    pc->r = sqrt(x*x + y*y);
    pc->theta = atan2(y, x);
    return pc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this function

```
struct polar_coordinate * polar(double x, double y){
   struct polar_coordinate pc;
   pc.r = sqrt(x*x + y*y);
   pc.theta = atan2(y,x);
   return &pc;
}
```

You are  returning the address of a local variable, which will be destroyed when the function returns.
And later in `main()` you are trying to access it

```
pc.r = sqrt(x*x + y*y);
pc.theta = atan2(y,x);
```

Comment: But what about when I use the rewritten function?

Comment: In the rewritten version, you've declared a pointer, but not made it point at anything.  You either need to be `malloc()`ing some memory inside the function (and `free()`ing it after use) or passing in the address of a `polar_coordinate` structure for the function to initialise.

Answer (score 0):

In the function `struct polar_coordinate * polar(double x, double y)` you are returning a local instance of `polar_coordinate` which will be destroyed at the end of the function scope.

You have to allocate your return variable before returning it.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a pointer to a local variable which goes out of scope when the function returns. But your fix causes a segmentation fault because you are using an *uninitialised pointer*. Here are two ways you can deal with it (without passing an extra argument)

```
struct polar_coordinate *polar(double x, double y){
    struct polar_coordinate * pc;
    pc = malloc(sizeof (struct polar_coordinate));
    if (pc == NULL)
        exit(1);
    pc->r = sqrt(x*x + y*y);
    pc->theta = atan2(y,x);
    return pc;
}
```

This returns a memory pointer which the caller will have to free and without that, repetitive calls will cause a memory leak.

Another way is by using a static local variable.

```
struct polar_coordinate *polar(double x, double y){
    static struct polar_coordinate pc;
    pc.r = sqrt(x*x + y*y);
    pc.theta = atan2(y,x);
    return &pc;
}
```

The disadvantage of this method is that subsequent calls to the function overwrite the `struct`.