# Error: Abort trap 6 - String obfuscation

Tags: c, string, obfuscation, abort

I am trying to write code for String Obfuscation but it gives me Abort trap: 6 error while running. Any ideas are much appreciated:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

char* readLine_str_test_encrypt();
char* readLine_str_test_decrypt();

int main () { //body 

printf("%s\n", readLine_str_test_encrypt());

printf("%s\n", readLine_str_test_decrypt());


}

char* readLine_str_test_decrypt() {
static unsigned char string[9] = {100, 115, 119, 114, 90, 127, 120, 115, 22};

static int i = 0;

for (; i < 9; ++i) {
    string[i] ^= 22;
}

return (char*)string;
}

char* readLine_str_test_encrypt()
{
static unsigned char string[9] = "readLine";
char output[9];
char* output_start=output;
static int i =0;
for(; i < 9; ++i)
{
    //string[i] = string[i]^22;
    output_start += sprintf(output_start,"%d",string[i]^22);

}

return output_start;
}
```

My decrypt function is running successfully.

Comment: for readability and ease of understanding by us humans: 1) consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  2)  separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a blank line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `readLine_str_test_encrypt` you are returning a pointer to variable `output`. This variable is a local variable and goes out of scope when the function exits.

Change it to

```
static char output[9];
```

and the error goes away.

Read more as to why you should not return a local variable [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824342/returning-a-local-variable-from-function-in-c).

Answer (score 2):

the posted code is:

1. including a header file those contents are not used
2. trying to 'sprintf()` a 3 char integer into a single byte
3. returning pointers to local variables
4. is not terminating the strings to be printed with a NUL byte

Note: `size_t` is a well known definition for `unsigned long int`

The following suggested code corrects all of the above problems and a few others.

```
#include <stdio.h>   // printf()
#include <stdlib.h>  // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE, malloc(), free()
//#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>  // strlen()

char* readLine_str_test_encrypt( char *, size_t );
char* readLine_str_test_decrypt( char *, size_t );


int main ( void )
{ //body
    char string[] = "readLine";

    char * encryptedString = readLine_str_test_encrypt( string, strlen(string) );
    // Note: the encrypted string may not be printable
    printf("%s\n", encryptedString );

    char * decryptedString = readLine_str_test_decrypt( encryptedString, strlen(string) );
    printf( "%s\n", decryptedString );

    free( encryptedString );
    free( decryptedString );
} // end function: main


char* readLine_str_test_decrypt( char *encryptedString, size_t length)
{
    char *string = NULL;

    if( NULL == ( string = malloc( length +1) ) )
    {// then malloc failed
        perror( "malloc for decrypted string failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, malloc successful

    for ( size_t i=0; encryptedString[i]; ++i )
    {
        string[i] = encryptedString[i] ^22;
    }

    string[length] = '\0';

    return string;
} // end function: readLine_str_test_decrypt


char* readLine_str_test_encrypt( char *stringToEncrypt, size_t length )
{
    char *output = NULL;

    if( NULL == (output = malloc( length+1 ) ) )
    { // then, malloc failed
        perror( "malloc for work area failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, malloc successful

    for( size_t i=0; stringToEncrypt[i]; ++i)
    {
        output[i] = stringToEncrypt[i] ^22;
    }

    output[length] = '\0';

    return output;
} // end function: readLine_str_test_encrypt
```

the output from the above code is:

```
dswrZxs
readLine
```