# how does printf change the return value of a function?

Tags: c

With the printf statement `printf("new s3 string (in locate function) is \"%s\" \n",s3)`, code works properly

but when `printf("new s3 string (in locate function) is \"%s\" \n",s3)` is commented, the code returns `null`

how is `printf` affecting the `return` value?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char * locate(char * s1,char * s2,int index) 
{
    printf("s1 string is \"%s\" \n",s1);
    printf("s2 string is \"%s\" \n",s2);

    int i=0,j=0, k;
    char s3[100];    

    while(i<=index)
    {
        s3[i]=s1[i];
        i++;
    }
    k=i;

    while(s2[j]!='\0')
    {
        s3[i]=s2[j];
        i++; j++;
    }

    while(s1[k]!='\0')
    {
        s3[i]=s1[k];
        i++;k++;
    }

    s3[i]='\0';

    //printf("new s3 string (in locate function) is \"%s\" \n",s3);

    return ((char *)s3);
}


int main(void) 
{
    char * s1="my name shwetha";
    char * s2="is ";
    s1=locate(s1,s2,7);

    printf("Final Inserted string S1 is \"%s\" \n",s1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [returning a local variable from function in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824342/returning-a-local-variable-from-function-in-c)

Answer (score 8):

`s3` goes out of scope (it leaves the function it was created in), so it has undefined behavior either way. You need to either create `s3` in `main` and pass it in as another parameter, or use heap allocation via `malloc()` which is managed by the OS.

Comment: Just a suggestion , instead of  _"it leaves the function it was created in"_ , it would be suited to say that it is freed from stack as function it is declared in is terminated .

Answer (score 1):

Your code returns the pointer to the local variable `s3`. Declared as such, it goes out of scope (gets released from stack memory) on `return`; when programmer neglects it, it's a common "generator" of program's undefined behavior. Two solutions are possible:

1. Dynamically allocating (and subsequently freeing) the variable, as suggested in the other answer.
2. Modifying the storage duration of the variable, by declaring it `static char s3[100]`

Please, also see this [related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824342/returning-a-local-variable-from-function-in-c).

Comment: char * s4=s3;
    return (s4);                           Will this also work?  Because char * is stored in data  segment right? So it should be available after exiting the function, correct?

Comment: You only give the returned _pointer_ a local name, @PyRookie, so nothing else should change for the compiler: memory that it points to stays the same. If you are more curious, try to compile into assembly language and compare the resulting codes line by line. (-: