# strcpy and strcat in Keil C compiler

Tags: c, printf, malloc, strcpy, keil

I used this code to print some string,but it does not print any thing.
What is the problem?

```
char* getNotFilledEncryptionParams(void)
{
    char* nofilledStr;
    char tmp[3];
    const char * arr[]= {" P,"," Q,"," A,"," B,"," C,"," R,"," S0,","S1,","S2,","F1,","G1"};


   for(i=0;i<11;i++)
   {
      if(filledParams[i] == 0)
      {
        strcpy(tmp,arr[i]);
        strcat(nofilledStr,tmp);
      }
   }

return nofilledStr;
}
```

Usage:

```
int main(void){

    char *remaining;

    remaining = getNotFilledEncryptionParams();
    printf("\r\n Remaining item:%s",remaining);

}
```

I think the problem is in `const char * arr[]` and I changed it,but the problem remains.

Comment: For one thing, tmp[3] should be at least 4 characters wide to accomodate the NULL when you use strcpy(). What is filledParams?

Comment: that is an integer array . @clarasoft-it

Comment: Dragging the strings to append through this `tmp` variable is useless. You can directly append `arr[i]` to the result string once you have allocated space for it.

Comment: @clarasoft-it: `NULL` is a null pointer constant. You mean the null character, `'\0'`.

Comment: Regarding the title, I'm fairly sure this has nothing to do with any editor.

Comment: @keith Thompson Yes, you are right, I meant the null byte which has value zero (a char is really an integer).

Comment: There are so many mistakes in this code, really you should learn the basics of C before continuing with whatever you're doing.  [Here is a list of resources](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You didn't allocate any memory for `noFilledStr`, so its value is indeterminate and `strcat(noFilledStr, tmp)` is undefined.

   Use `malloc` to allocate memory and initialize `noFilledStr` with the returned pointer:

   ```
   char* noFilledStr = malloc(number_of_bytes);
   ```
2. The strings in `arr` are `char[4]`, not `char[3]` (do not forget the null byte!). `tmp` is too small to hold them, so `strcpy(tmp, arr[i])` writes out of bounds.

Comment: can I replace char* noFilledStr to char noFilledStr[30] ?

Comment: Also, you would be returning data that isn't allocated anywhere, when you create local data in a function, it is temporary and only created on the stack.  If you want to return the string then you should allocate the memory and return the start address of the allocated memory.

Comment: @Hamid No, because you return a pointer to it from the function and the automatic array `char noFilledStr[30]` would have ended its lifetime then. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824342/returning-a-local-variable-from-function-in-c).

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to build the string to return in the location pointed to by `nofilledStr` but this pointer is pointing somewhere as you do not initialize it. You could use a sufficiently large static `char[]` array if you do not have to deal with multiple threads. Otherwise, use `malloc()` and require the caller to `free()` the returned string when he is done with it.