# returning pointer to a local variable

Tags: c++, function, pointers

What happens when a pointer to a local variable is returned by a function?

for example

```
int* foo()
{
    int local;
    int* ptr = &local;
    return ptr;
}
```

will compiler issue a warning or will it compile and produce unexpected results??

Comment: why don't you try?

Comment: int* foo()
    {
        int local = 42;
        int* ptr = &local;
        return ptr;
    }
    int main ()
    {
      return *(foo());
    }

Comment: This should be obvious: the lifetime of a local variable is the function invocation.

Comment: "why don't you try?" is actually a bad advice in this case.  It is asked before and it is undefined behavior meaning that trying it can get different results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar kind of question has already been asked : [Stack Overflow, local pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824342/returning-a-local-variable-from-function-in-c)

There are somethings in C which are left for compiler vendor to implement in the way they like. The behaviour of such things are not defined by the creators. Compiler vendors can implement such things as in the way they feel easy and faster. This falls in the same category. The behaviour is undefined and depends on the compiler you are using.

One more such thing is use of more than one pre-increment (pre-decrement) and/or post-increment (post-decrement). When the same code runs on different compilers, you'll may get different output.

Comment: For more information on UB, better refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior where you can find all the info you need

Answer (score 4):

> What happens when a pointer to a local variable is returned by a function?

Undefined behaviour. Anything can happen. The compiler will give you a warning.

This is `g++` warning for that mistake:

```
g++ -Wall -std=c++11 -O3 test.cpp -o test
warning: function returns address of local variable [-Wreturn-local-addr]
```

Comment: GCC doesn't give any warning, even with -Wall -Wextra -Werror

Comment: @WARhead Please read this on what is undefined behavior: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior

Comment: You should use g++ for .cpp file

Comment: *should give a warning. static analyzer really really should give a warning. otherwise they really failed :)

Comment: Yep, I didn't notice the c++ tag, sorry @artm

Comment: @EliotB. there is a warning, see the `g++` flag

Comment: Both GCC and Clang warn for `return &local;`, but not for `int* p = &local; return p;` cc @EliotB.

Comment: @chris I read your comments more carefully now. That's strange `gcc` and `clang` doesn't give a warning; but `g++` does