# Count greater elements on right side of a current element in an array

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to count the number of elements greater than the element on the right side of the array. Here my function goes.

```
int* SurpassersKing(int input1_size, int* input1,int* output_size)
    {
        int i,k;
        int count[input1_size];
        for  (i = 0; i < input1_size; i++)
            count[i] = 0;


        for ( i = 0; i < input1_size; i++) 
        {
            for ( k = i + 1; k <input1_size; k++) 
                {
                        if (input1[i] < input1[k]) {
                                 count[i]++;
                        }
                }
        } 

        return count;
    }
```

This is my function where I am counting greater elements in an array.

So in this following code snippet i have wriiten the main function , declaring all the veriable like output_size,counting array ,i ,k as an index for the arrays and printing the stuff , and calling counting function .

```
int main() {
    int output_size;
    int* output;

    int ip1_size = 0;
    int ip1_i;
    scanf("%d\n", &ip1_size);
    int ip1[ip1_size];
    for(ip1_i = 0; ip1_i < ip1_size; ip1_i++) {
        int ip1_item;
        scanf("%d", &ip1_item);

        ip1[ip1_i] = ip1_item;
    }
    output = SurpassersKing(ip1_size,ip1,&output_size);
    int output_i;
    for(output_i=0; output_i < output_size; output_i++) {

        printf("%d\n", output[output_i]);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

but i am not getting the output required so what can i do to improve this.

Comment: Please put all code into the question as formatted text. Not as an external link and certainly not as an image.

Comment: it is an image that i attached

Comment: **not** as an image

Comment: ok updated......

Comment: What do you mean by "right side of array"? Can you give a sample input and a sample output?

Comment: What you want is not clear to me. Pleas explain (or give example) results you expected?

Comment: @Logman array_size
7
array_input
2
7
5
3
0
8
1
array_output
4
1
1
1
2
0
0@VHS

Comment: `return count;`. That's wrong. You must not return a pointer to a local variable from a function. It is invalid once the function exits.

Comment: what should I return?

Comment: Two common options: 1. return dynamically allocated memory. 2. Caller passes in a buffer that the function uses for output results.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [returning a local variable from function in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824342/returning-a-local-variable-from-function-in-c)

Comment: In the current scenario what should I return to get it on the road.

Comment: @swa, see my answer.

Comment: ok................

Answer (score 1):

Your logic to calculate the count of the numbers to the right side is correct. Only problem is you can't return arrays like that from a function. Try following:

Replace

`int count[input1_size];`

with

`int * count = malloc(input1_size*sizeof(int));`

And then in the `main` function

Add

`free(output);`

just before the return statement.

Comment: Could I use free(output); in the local  function

Comment: You cannot free it until you complete using it. You complete using it in the last loop in your main function

Comment: Is there any way to not to use free(output) and make it on the road

Comment: Or how to return array along with output_size to the main function thanks in advance

Comment: Output size is always same as input size in this case.

Comment: yeah output size is input size in this but how to return the result

Comment: @swa, I don't understand why you don't want to free the memory pointed to by `output`. If you can explain the reason, I can suggest a workaround.

Comment: The restriction is I can't modify the code present in the main function.I have to use the given main code and write a function with the present main function so to run the entire code so to speak

Comment: Well, then, you are out of choices. If you don't free up the memory, your program will still work. But it will leak memory.

Comment: Thanks i got it i run the program using java and issue get resolved thanks once again

Answer (score 1):

Oso your code has a few errors i found when i tried to compile.

1. This is  a c code so use #include
2. Inside the function SurpassersKing you are trying to return array count which is not allowed. Never return local variables unless it is dynamically created.
3. The output_size never gets initilized.

This is the final code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int* SurpassersKing(int input1_size, int* input1)
{
    int i,k;
    int * count = (int*)malloc(input1_size*sizeof(int));
    for  (i = 0; i < input1_size; i++)
        *(count + i) = 0;


    for ( i = 0; i < input1_size; i++) 
    {
        for ( k = i + 1; k <input1_size; k++) 
            {
                    if (input1[i] < input1[k]) {
                             count[i]++;
                    }
            }
    } 

    return count;
}

int main() {
// your code goes here
int output_size;
int* output;

int ip1_size = 0;
int ip1_i;
int output_i;

printf("Enter the size:\n");
scanf("%d",&ip1_size);
int ip1[ip1_size];
for(ip1_i = 0; ip1_i < ip1_size; ip1_i++) {
    scanf("%d",%ip1[ip1_i]);
}
output = SurpassersKing(ip1_size,ip1);
output_size = ip1_size;

for(output_i=0; output_i < output_size; output_i++) {

    printf("%d\n",output[output_i]");

}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: If the question is c you cant use iostream, namespace and also inbetween declarations

Comment: I am not expert in C but can you do `int ip1[ip1_size];` if `ip1_size` is not constant?

Comment: @DavidBowling...ok

Comment: @Logman-- this is a variable length array, which was added to the Standard in C99. It was made optional in C11, but seems to be well-supported by implementations of C11.

Comment: @Arvindsinc2 dynamic table size could be difficult to allocate on function stack. Normally you allocate dynamic memory on heap.

Comment: I have initialised the output_size in the main() by making output_size = ip1_size...you had declared output_size but never initialised it with a value.