# Linked list function returns address of local variable

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm implementing a linked list program in C and the create_node function gives a warning: function returns address of local variable. I've read about using malloc, but I'd like to understand what the original problem and solution would be without it. Thanks.

```
struct list_node_s* Create_node(int val, struct list_node_s* node_p) {
   struct list_node_s temp;

   temp.data = val;
   temp.next_p = node_p;
   return &temp;
}  /* Create_node */
```

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/q/4824342/694576 if not a duplicate to.

Comment: It is something which very hard to explain on one leg but i will tried to be simpale

The problem is when you create a variable without **malloc**  - Behind the Scenes you put the variable on the stack - Segment of memory which save somethings about your current code segment  .

Comment: when you jump to function you are add things to your stack from some point and when you finish (return from un-void function or finishes void function) you free all the things that you save from the enterance point.

That mean - in your specific code you try to return address of something that you save on the stack but when you return you freed the stack - you try to return somthing that you "freed".

.

Comment: Instead in malloc you have another code segment which called **Heap**  the difference between the heap -
at the Heap when you allocates variable (do malloc) you tell to OS - "Hey There, i'm the boss and don't touch that variable while i don't tell else" 

I tried to be simple but the best advice is to read about function call, Stack segment , Heap Segment..

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `temp` variable is a *local* variable. It has function scope so it only exists as long as your program is in the function. This is usually implemented with a *stack*.

You should use `malloc` to get memory from the *heap* which is where all dynamic allocations are made from. This way the list and its nodes will exist until you explicitly destroy them with `free`.

The only other solution, which I don't recommend, is to build your list using recursive function calls. And as long as you use the list *never return*.

I saw that done one time. It was hideous. But possible.