# Type of address and pointers in c

Tags: c, pointers, memory-address

I have 2 questions about pointers in c.

1) from my understanding the `&` returns the memory address of a variable. For example:

```
int x=10;    
int *p=&x;
```

So I think that the `&` will return the memory address of `x` and that memory address is type `int*` because the variable type of `x` is `int`.

Also because the type of the address is  `int*`  I believe that is the reason that only an `int*` (and `void *`) pointer can point in the address (they are the same type).

Any thoughts about that? comments? I don't know if I am correct.

2) It's about the void pointer. I know that the `void*` pointer can point to any type of variable. For example

```
int x=10;
void *ptr=&x;
```

Now I have a function:

```
void * foo(some parameters)
{
  // just for this example let's say that I return the address of a local variable

  // I know that is wrong to do so because when the foo ends
  // the local variables deallocate

  int k=10;
  void *ptr=&k;
  return ptr;    
}
```

So my pointer is type `void` but it points to  `int*` memory address. So `ptr` will save the address of `k` and when I return `ptr` the address of `k`  is returned which is type `int*` . But my function is type `void*`.

What is happening here?

Comment: Please edit your question and fix code formatting and indention.

Comment: Please ask only one question at the time.

Comment: The pointer returned by the function you show will not be valid, as it points to a local variable inside the function, and that variables life-time ends when the function ends.

Comment: Somewhat of topic, but returning the pointer to a local variable is a bad idea, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824342/returning-a-local-variable-from-function-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

According to the C Standard (6.3.2.3 Pointers)

> 1 A pointer to void may be converted to or from a pointer to any
>   object type. A pointer to any object type may be converted to a
>   pointer to void and back again; the result shall compare equal to the
>   original pointer.

So for example in this code snippet

```
int x = 10;
void *p = &x;
```

the expression `&x` in the right side of the assignment has the type `int *`. According to the quote it may be converted to pointer of the type `void *` in the left side of the assignment.

Answer (score 1):

1) Yes all of that is correct.

2) The type of the pointed-at data remains `int` no matter what kind of pointer that points at it. (This is known as *effective type* in formal C.) In your example you return a void pointer so that's the type the caller gets. The information of what type it pointed at is lost, from the point you do `void *ptr=&k;` and onward. This is why void pointers are problematic to use.

Answer (score 0):

1) You are correct
2) It is simply returning a `void *` that is pointing to `k` - a local variable. (Any pointers can be cast to void pointers).

You are correct in saying that you should not use the returned value as `k` no longer exists