# Memory leak when creating & destroying threads

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I'm writing a program that performs some processing on each packet received. I've taken some of the multithreading code and put it into its own program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

struct pktstruct {
    //u_char *args; - Not used
    const struct pcap_pkthdr *head;
    const u_char *packt;
    int thread_no;
};
void* packet_handler(void *arguments);
void handler_dispatcher(u_char *args, const struct pcap_pkthdr *header, const u_char *packet);
pthread_t threads[20];
volatile sig_atomic_t thread_done[20];

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i ++){
        thread_done[i] = 0;
    }

    while (1) {
        handler_dispatcher(NULL,NULL,NULL);
    }
}

void* packet_handler(void *arguments)
{
    struct pktstruct *args = arguments;
    printf("Hello %d\n", args->thread_no);
    thread_done[args->thread_no] = 1;
    return NULL;
}

void handler_dispatcher(u_char *args, const struct pcap_pkthdr *header, const u_char *packet){
    struct pktstruct pkt;
    pkt.head = header;
    pkt.packt = packet;
    for (int t = 0; t < 20; t++) {
        if ( thread_done[t] ) {
            //printf("Thread %d is done! Joining...\n", t);
            pthread_join(threads[t], NULL);
            thread_done[t] = 0;
        }
    }
    for (int q = 0; q < 20; q++) {
        if ( !thread_done[q] ) {
            pkt.thread_no = q;

            pthread_create(&threads[q], NULL, &packet_handler, &pkt);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Originally I was just spawning a thread for each packet. I'm not very familiar with C so it took me a while to realize stuff like threads don't clean up, return NULL is better than pthread_exit(NULL) etc.

The program prints a bunch of "Hello"s and then stops functioning properly. HTOP shows 256G for VIRT and 266M for RES, but the only reason they stop growing is because the program stops working.

I understand that it would be 'good design' to use mutexes, however I thought that since I'm checking for free slots in each iteration, surely even if I miss a thread just becoming available, next iteration I will know about it.

To be fully honest, I tried using mutexes too -locking and unlocking before and after the 'for' loops in handler_dispatcher, as well as before and after the assignment in packet_handler- but the program again stops working after a brief moment with 256G VIRT and 266M RES.

What is it that I'm doing wrong?

Edit: Added headers. Compile with gcc test.c -o test -Wall -lpthread

Comment: `return NULL;` from a thread function is exactly equal to `pthread_exit(NULL);`.

Comment: Why are you initializing `thread_done` to all true? That indicates that all threads are done before you have even started any threads. And with the weird order of code you have in the `handler_dispatcher` function, that will cause it to immediately attempt to join a thread that doesn't exist.

Comment: Also, you pass a pointer to a ***local*** variable to the thread. That local variable will ends its life when the `handler_dispatcher` function returns, leaving the thread with an invalid pointer. *Furthermore* the way you call the `handler_dispatcher` function in the example you show us, it will be very likely that the memory occupied by the `pkt` variable will be the same in every call of `handler_dispatcher`. Meaning you pass the same pointer to all threads, making them inadvertently share the a single structure.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude You're right about the initialisation, that was my bad when copying over the code. Edited the question. I've observed 'return NULL;' to be less resource-intensive than 'pthread_exit(NULL);', but then again I might just be doing it wrong. Regarding the local scope of the variable, I'm not sure I understand; the program stops without error, and the count never resets. Printing 'thread_no' results in different numbers being printed.

Comment: This cannot be your real code, there are compilation errors.

Comment: @n.m. Did you add the required headers?

Comment: You know that local variables only exists in the function they are defined in? And that you [can't return a pointer to a local variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824342/returning-a-local-variable-from-function-in-c)? It's the same issue here, once the function `handler_dispatcher` ends, all its local variables cease to exist. That should have been taught by just about any decent class, tutorial or book.

Comment: We can only show errors in the code you have posted, not in the code you want to run. The first error I see is `thread_done[q] = 0;` This does not compile, as `q` is not declared. You need to post a [mcve].

Comment: @n.m. I think I fixed it, try now.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Unfortunately none of those were available :(

Comment: This is still not a [mcve]. It cannot be compiled as it lacks necessary `#include` directives.

Comment: Think about what would happen if you replaced the printf in the thread function with a sleep of 1h.

Comment: @n.m. Added headers and compilation instructions. Replacing printf with sleep means that a bunch of threads are created which just sleep. I guess my problem then is that I'm passing pointers to local variables.

Answer (score 0):

You never ever use `volatile` variables to communicate between threads. `volatile` does not imply `atomic`. Accessing a non-atomic variable from more than one thread is undefined. But let's pretend for the sake of learning that this is not an issue, and look at your two loops.

First loop:

```
 for (int t = 0; t < 20; t++) {
       if ( thread_done[t] ) {
           //printf("Thread %d is done! Joining...\n", t);
           pthread_join(threads[t], NULL);
           thread_done[t] = 0;
       }
  }
```

At first call of `handler_dispatcher`, there are no threads yet, and all `thread_done` members are 1. You are calling `pthread_join` 20 times on something that are not valid threads. This is undefined, but suppose you have survived this somehow. You set all `thread_done` to 0.

Second loop:

```
for (int q = 0; q < 20; q++) {
    if ( !thread_done[q] ) {
        pkt.thread_no = q;

        pthread_create(&threads[q], NULL, &packet_handler, &pkt);
        break;
    }
}
```

When the function is called for the first time, this loop creates a single thread.

When the function is called for the second time, that thread is probably still running, so the first loop does nothing. (`printf` is a slow function that does IO, so it is safe to assume it takes 1000s times more time than a single iteration of your `while(1)` loop in main`).`thread_done`is zero, so you create a new thread. The new thread ID overwrites the original`pthread_t` object, which is lost forever, so the original thread is impossible to join.

When the function is called for the *third* time, the *second* thread you have created is probably still running. So you create a new thread. The new thread ID overwrites the original `pthread_t` object, which is lost forever, so the original thread is impossible to join.

When the function is called for the *fourth* time, the *third* thread you have created is probably still running. So you create a new thread. The new thread ID overwrites the original `pthread_t` object, which is lost forever, so the original thread is impossible to join.

---

When the function is called for the 5380th time, the very first thread you have created has finally terminated. It sets its `thread_done` flag, and your first loop does a `join`. Only it joins not the first thread, but 5379th. This call blocks until that thread is done too. Then the sequence restarts.

All in all, I think this sequence of events is probably not quite what you want. Passing pointers to local variables around is but a cherry on top of this pie. I suggest getting a proper cookbook.

---

This was written when `thread_done[i] = 0;` was `thread_done[i] = 1;` but this doesn't change the outcome too much.