# C structs vs typedef struct question

Tags: c, struct, typedef

So my question is multifaceted.

For the purpose of understanding C (not C++) I believe the following code:

```
struct Foo { int bar; };
```

creates a custom type that I can use, but so does this:

```
typedef Foo { int bar; };
```

The only difference I have seen is whether or not I have to use the "struct" keyword before the variable of the type Foo. What are the differences that cause this behavior?

Comment: See also [this interesting answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252780/why-should-we-typedef-a-struct-so-often-in-c/254250#254250) to a similar question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is:

```
struct Foo { int bar; };
```

creates structure type `{ int bar; }` named Foo. I.e. full type name is `struct Foo`.

```
typedef Foo { int bar; };
```

creates alias `Foo` for unnamed structure type `{ int bar; }`

However I'm not sure yours syntax is fully correct for strict C, but somehow it's OK for your compiler. Or it creates something different, but accidentaly it works, C syntax can be very tricky. Anyway second statement should be:

```
typedef struct { int bar; } Foo;
```

For further reference [you can use this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#Structures).

Comment: -1, Even though this is an old answer, it nevertheless is incorrect. `typedef Foo { int bar; };` is simply invalid C syntax.

Answer (score 6):

`struct` introduces a new type, but `typedef` merely creates an alias for another type.  This declaration creates a new type called `struct Foo`:

```
struct Foo { int bar; };
```

This declaration is simply invalid:

```
typedef Foo { int bar; };
```

However, this declaration is valid, and creates a new, unnamed type, and also creates an alias to that type called `Foo`:

```
typedef struct { int bar; } Foo;
```

You can also create an alias to a named type - this creates an alias to the type `struct Foo` called `Foo`:

```
typedef struct Foo Foo;
```

These two names are completely interchangeable - you can pass a `struct Foo` to a function declared as taking an argument of type `Foo`, for example.

You can create aliases for any types, including built-in types.  For example, you can create an alias for `int` called `Foo`:

```
typedef int Foo;
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe your syntax is incorrect.  `typedef Foo { int bar; };` should be `typedef Foo { int bar; } MyFoo;`

The reason people would then use the typedef is so they can drop the struct in declarations.  I.e.:

```
struct Foo myFoo;
//vs.
MyFoo myFoo;
```

Answer (score 0):

when i am going to compile this code

```
typedef Foo { int bar; };
```

it says compile error

```
error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘{’ token
```