# C style/C++ correctness, is struct/union/enum tag same as type name bad in any way?

Tags: c++, c, coding-style, typedef

The following definition of MyStruct (tag MyStruct) and type definition of type MyStruct seems  perfectly compillable by gcc (at least 4.6.2) and by g++.

```
typedef struct MyStruct {
  int a;
  int b;
} MyStruct;
```

**My question is: is it somehow error-prone (in C and/or C++) or bad style to use tag name the same as the type name?**

According to http://www.eetimes.com/discussion/programming-pointers/4024450/Tag-vs-Type-Names it is not:

> I've never understood why they use different names for the tag and the typedef when one name will do just fine:
>
> ```
> typedef struct tree_node tree_node;
> ```

But often I've seen code styled like:

1. `typedef struct tagMyStruct {...} MyStruct;`
2. typedef struct myStruct {...} MyStruct;`
3. `typedef struct _MyStruct {...} MyStruct;` < yes, I know about underscore + capital letter

In each case someone went to some extent to make tag name *differ* from type name. Are there any practical reasons behind it?

Side note: I use C++ compiler but I would like to be C compatible with those definitions (I know this is bad style for c++). For reasons of maintaining usability of some debug tools, I need all the tag names to be meaningful (not the automatically generated __unknown_something tags in case of unnamed structs you can, for example, see in visual studio class view).

Same issue/question apply to unions and enums.

Comment: As long as you don't have other identifiers with the same name as the tag, you're ok with using the name both for the tag and typedef.

Comment: I assume people avoid using the same name to be on the safe side, because the fact that `struct foo` won't conflict with `foo` isn't common knowledge, and intuition of a programmer would recommend to avoid reusing the same name.

Comment: In C, many would argue it is bad style to use the typedef at all, so its name is irrelevant.

Comment: @oddstar: whereas although people do that, actually the reverse is safer: reusing the same name in both contexts (struct tag and regular identifier) means you've reserved that name in both, which prevents any confusing non-conflicts if someone else tries to use the same name in the other context.

Comment: @Steve Opaque types and de-obfuscating declarations (eg typedeffing a function pointer type) are, IMO, the only appropriate uses of the typedef.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Language wise it is perfectly ok both in C and C++, as tag names exist in a separate name space (not `namespace`).

In C++ it is definitely bad style to use the `typedef` at all, as it is redundant. You can use both `MyStruct` and `struct MyStruct` whether you have the `typedef` or not.

If you think C compatibility is more important than C++ style, that is your choice. :-)

Comment: "as it is redundant" - formally it's not redundant, since it makes a difference. Using it stops some joker from declaring a function (or other entity) named `MyStruct`. In practice, you just count on people not to be that committed to practical jokes in the workplace.

Answer (score 0):

The 'struct Foo' declares struct in different namespace. So, 'struct Foo' and 'Foo' cannot interfere.

The reason for doing `typedef struct _foo {} foo;` is not very clear for me. Maybe it is relict of pointer (`typedef struct _foo {} foo, *Pfoo;`) typedefing.

Comment: It should be noted that your answer is C-specific.

Comment: So you say there is nothing wrong and no risk with naming tag and type the same?

Answer (score 0):

Technically, there is no reason that the names need be different and a great deal of code has been written using the same name for both identifiers. The important thing is to be consistent within your own code.

It can be argued that overusing `typedef` pollutes the namespace, and that can be true. The rule-of-thumb that I use is: If I'm going to use it a lot use a `typedef`, if not don't.

Also, if I'm using a `typedef` I don't name the `struct`, so I'll code it just like this:

```
typedef struct {
    int a;
    int b;
} struct_t;
```

That way I have to use it consistently, and consistency is the key to good coding style.

Comment: I've been also using your style, but for some reason, unnamed structs are apparently harder to view using MS symbol engine (this may be msc/visual studio specific). You can look into your .PDB file and see, that actually tag names are stored there, not type names, at least that is what I saw.

Comment: Since I don't use MS tools, I'm not familiar with that problem. But it is true that you won't get a class name in the symbol table with a `typedef` of an anonymous `struct`. If that gives you trouble in debugging, then you may want to use a different strategy. Truth is, I don't use typedef nearly as much with C++ as I used to with C.

Answer (score 0):

Because C (can be) implemented a one-pass compiler, self-referencing the typedef when it is not created is an error. Eg, this is invalid,

```
typedef struct {
  Foo *next;
  int i;
} Foo;
```

thus,

```
typedef struct tagFoo {
  struct tagFoo *next;
  int i;
} Foo;
```

when you want to refer to it as `Foo` and not `struct Foo`. See [Why should we typedef a struct so often in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252780/why-should-we-typedef-a-struct-so-often-in-c) for discussion.