# Assign a pointer to a struct that is a member of a struct of the same type to another pointer to a struct of the same type

Tags: c, pointers, struct

This question sounds super confusing even for me, and it may seem obvious or already answered, but I have searched a lot and although I found interesting things, I didn't find an answer exactly for my question. Here is some **C** code that will show much better my doubt:

```
typedef struct Node_struct {
   char keyLine[100];
   int occurrences;
   struct Node* leftChild;
   struct Node* rightChild;
   struct Node* parent;
} Node;

typedef struct Tree_struct {
   Node* root;
} Tree;

int insertNode(Tree* myTree, Node* newNode) {
    ...
    Node* currentNode = myTree->root;
    ...
    if (caseSenCmpString(newNode->keyLine, currentNode->keyLine) == -1) {
        currentNode = (Node*)currentNode->leftChild;
    }
    ...
 }
```

Is this code correct? Since `currentNode` is of type `Node*`, and `currentNode->leftChild` is of type `struct Node*`, I had to cast `(Node*)currentNode->leftChild` so that it could be assigned to `currentNode`. But I am not sure if this is correct, necessary, or if there is a better way to do the same.

Similarly, I also have this:

```
Node* coverNode = NULL;
...
coverNode->leftChild = (struct Node*)newNode;
```

Comment: Related:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588623/self-referential-struct-definition

Comment: The name `Node` is a synonym for `struct Node`. (For any `typedef X Y;`, `Y` becomes a synonym for `X` — where in your case, `X` is `struct Node` and `Y` is `Node`.)  The cast in `currentNode = (Node*)currentNode->leftChild;` is unnecessary because it is a no-op — the types `struct Node *` and `Node *` are two names for the same pointer type.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler What about `typedef struct Node_struct { /* ... */ struct Node* leftChild; /* ... */ } Node;` ... are `struct Node_struct` and `struct Node` and `Node` the same? I get that `Node` is the same as `struct Node_struct`, but what about the `struct Node *` used to declare a member of the struct?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler You may thank me properly later. Hush ... go fix your ;)

Comment: @Swordfish: Thanks for pointing out that I'd misread the question.  I've 'adjusted' (extended) my answer to deal with 'practice' as well as 'theory'.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler \*hands-bonbon\*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### What should be written

Suppose the code in the question were written like this:

```
typedef struct Node {     // Not Node_struct as in the question!
   char keyLine[100];
   int occurrences;
   struct Node* leftChild;
   struct Node* rightChild;
   struct Node* parent;
} Node;
```

Then the name `Node` would be a synonym (alias) for `struct Node`. (For any `typedef X Y;`, `Y` becomes a synonym for type `X` — where in your case, `X` would be `struct Node` and `Y` would be Node.)

The cast in:

```
currentNode = (Node *)currentNode->leftChild;
```

would be unnecessary (but mostly harmless) because it would be a no-op — the types `struct Node *` and `Node *` would be two names for the same pointer type.  Similarly for:

```
coverNode->leftChild = (struct Node *)newNode;
```

The cast would be unnecessary but (mostly) harmless.  There would be a small risk of confusing people with the cast.  It is better to avoid casts when possible, and these would be better written without the casts:

```
currentNode = currentNode->leftChild;
coverNode->leftChild = newNode;
```

#### What is written

```
typedef struct Node_struct {
   char keyLine[100];
   int occurrences;
   struct Node* leftChild;
   struct Node* rightChild;
   struct Node* parent;
} Node;
```

Now we have three type names in play: `struct Node_struct`, `struct Node`, and `Node`.  In this case, `struct Node_struct` and `Node` are synonyms, and `struct Node` is an incomplete structure type (or, at least, it is not completed by any code in the question).  It is wholly unrelated to either `struct Node_struct` or `Node` except by the coincidence that it is referenced inside the structure.

With this notation, the casts are 'necessary' because you're converting between pointers to unrelated types (`struct Node *` and `struct Node_struct *`).  Fortunately, there are rules that say all structure type pointers are inter-convertible and must have the same size and alignment requirements (C11 [§6.2.5 Types ¶28](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.5p28) and [§6.3.2.3 Pointers ¶7](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p7)).

But you should drop the `_struct` part of `Node_struct` to make the rules of the first part of this answer apply.  In C, it is (IMO) sensible to use:

```
typedef struct SomeTag SomeTag;
```

so that you can subsequently use `SomeTag *` etc.  The first `SomeTag` is in the tags name space and does not conflict with the second `SomeTag`, which is in the ordinary identifiers name space.  See C11 [§6.2.3 Name spaces of identifiers](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.3).

See also:

- [Which part of the C standard allows this code to compile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12200096/)
- [Does the C standard consider that there are one or two `struct uperms_entry` types in this code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11697705/)
- [C style/C++ correctness — is `struct`, `union`, `enum` tag same as type name bad in any way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9534884/)

Answer (score 2):

In `c++`, when you say `struct Node`, `Node` [immediately] becomes a type. So, you could say:

```
struct Node {
    char keyLine[100];
    int occurrences;
    Node *leftChild;
    Node *rightChild;
    Node *parent;
};

struct Tree {
    Node *root;
};

int
insertNode(Tree *myTree, Node *newNode)
{
    Node *currentNode = myTree->root;
    if (caseSenCmpString(newNode->keyLine, currentNode->keyLine) == -1) {
        currentNode = currentNode->leftChild;
    }
}
```

---

But, in `c`, it is merely in the "tag" namespace and does *not* define a type. Thus, you want:

```
typedef struct Node {
    char keyLine[100];
    int occurrences;
    struct Node *leftChild;
    struct Node *rightChild;
    struct Node *parent;
} Node;

typedef struct Tree_struct {
    Node *root;
} Tree;

int
insertNode(Tree *myTree, Node *newNode)
{
    Node *currentNode = myTree->root;
    if (caseSenCmpString(newNode->keyLine, currentNode->keyLine) == -1) {
        currentNode = currentNode->leftChild;
    }
}
```

---

As an alternative, you can use a *forward declaration*:

```
// forward declaration
struct Node;
typedef struct Node Node;

struct Node {
    char keyLine[100];
    int occurrences;
    Node *leftChild;
    Node *rightChild;
    Node *parent;
};

typedef struct Tree_struct {
    Node *root;
} Tree;

int
insertNode(Tree *myTree, Node *newNode)
{
    Node *currentNode = myTree->root;
    if (caseSenCmpString(newNode->keyLine, currentNode->keyLine) == -1) {
        currentNode = currentNode->leftChild;
    }
}
```

---

Note that the `struct` name does *not* have to match the type name:

```
// forward declaration
struct Node_struct;
typedef struct Node_struct Node;

struct Node_struct {
    char keyLine[100];
    int occurrences;
    Node *leftChild;
    Node *rightChild;
    Node *parent;
};

typedef struct Tree_struct {
    Node *root;
} Tree;

int
insertNode(Tree *myTree, Node *newNode)
{
    Node *currentNode = myTree->root;
    if (caseSenCmpString(newNode->keyLine, currentNode->keyLine) == -1) {
        currentNode = currentNode->leftChild;
    }
}
```

---

To allow cross linking of your two structs, we could do:

```
// forward declaration
struct Node_struct;
typedef struct Node_struct Node;

struct Tree_struct;
typedef struct Tree_struct Tree;

struct Node_struct {
    char keyLine[100];
    int occurrences;
    Node *leftChild;
    Node *rightChild;
    Node *parent;
    Tree *tree;
};

struct Tree_struct {
    Node *root;
};

int
insertNode(Tree *myTree, Node *newNode)
{
    Node *currentNode = myTree->root;
    if (caseSenCmpString(newNode->keyLine, currentNode->keyLine) == -1) {
        currentNode = currentNode->leftChild;
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean the 'tag' namespace?  C11 [§6.2.3 Name spaces of identifiers](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.3)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks. Accurate as always. And, I marvel at how fast you were able to call up the online doc, find the relevant section, and post the link here.

Comment: I 'cheated' — I'd just written a very similar [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506366/c-pointer-to-struct-in-the-struct-definition#comment92498340_508990) to another answer to an old question, and still had the link stashed in my paste buffer, even.