# I don't understand why compiler is giving me error with this code

Tags: c, linux, gcc, clang, x86-64

I have the following C code, which looks very correct to me. However, the clang compiler (infact gcc or any other C compiler too) thinks otherwise.

```
typedef struct
{
    struct timeval td_start;
    struct timeval td_end;
} Timer;

void startTimer( struct Timer* ptimer ) 
{
    gettimeofday( &(ptimer->td_start), NULL );
}

void stopTimer( struct Timer* ptimer ) 
{
    gettimeofday( &(ptimer->td_end), NULL );
}
```

The compiler gives the following waring & error messages. Any idea what is wrong here?

```
./timing.h:14:25: warning: declaration of 'struct Timer' will not be visible
      outside of this function [-Wvisibility]
void startTimer( struct Timer* ptimer )
                        ^
./timing.h:16:27: error: incomplete definition of type 'struct Timer'
    gettimeofday( &(ptimer->td_start), NULL );
                    ~~~~~~^
./timing.h:14:25: note: forward declaration of 'struct Timer'
void startTimer( struct Timer* ptimer )
                        ^
./timing.h:19:24: warning: declaration of 'struct Timer' will not be visible
      outside of this function [-Wvisibility]
void stopTimer( struct Timer* ptimer )
                       ^
./timing.h:21:27: error: incomplete definition of type 'struct Timer'
    gettimeofday( &(ptimer->td_end), NULL );
                    ~~~~~~^
./timing.h:19:24: note: forward declaration of 'struct Timer'
void stopTimer( struct Timer* ptimer )
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Remove the `struct` keyword (it's not needed since you've already `typedef`ed the struct):

```
void startTimer( Timer* ptimer ) 
{
  ...

void stopTimer( Timer* ptimer ) 
{
  ...
```

Alternatively, remove the `typedef`:

```
struct Timer
{
    struct timeval td_start;
    struct timeval td_end;
};

void startTimer( struct Timer* ptimer ) 
{
  ...

void stopTimer( struct Timer* ptimer ) 
{
  ...
```

For more information, see [Why should we typedef a struct so often in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252780/why-should-we-typedef-a-struct-so-often-in-c)

Comment: A better solution: don't use the typedef!

Comment: William: But you have to prefix struct with a structure variable in ANSI C right! In C++ I agree struct is not needed. Not sure about C99 though.

Answer (score 4):

Either you

```
struct Timer
{
    struct timeval td_start;
    struct timeval td_end;
};

void startTimer( struct Timer* ptimer ) 
{
    gettimeofday( &(ptimer->td_start), NULL );
}
```

Or you

```
typedef struct
{
    struct timeval td_start;
    struct timeval td_end;
} Timer;

void startTimer( Timer* ptimer ) 
{
    gettimeofday( &(ptimer->td_start), NULL );
}
```

But don't mixup.

Answer (score 3):

You created a type called Timer, just delete the word struct before the function parameters, like this, for example:

```
void startTimer( Timer* ptimer ) 
{
    gettimeofday( &(ptimer->td_start), NULL );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The *reason* for the error is that, when you get here

```
void startTimer( struct Timer* ptimer )
```

there is no `struct Timer` in scope (just a typedef for an anonymous struct). So the compiler believes you want to declare a *new* type `struct Timer` and use a pointer to that as a parameter.

Actually doing that would be less than useful, as the type would just be visible *inside* the function. That would make it practically impossible to pass in a parameter from *outside* the function.

So the compiler says that, while possibly allowed by the language, this doesn't look like  a good idea!