# syntax of struct in C or nesC

Tags: c, struct, nesc

I have some `nesC`  code, and there is some sturct definitions like the example below:

```
typedef nx_struct serial_header {
  nx_am_addr_t dest;
  nx_am_addr_t src;
  nx_uint8_t length;
  nx_am_group_t group;
  nx_am_id_t type;
} serial_header_t;
```

I cant get the idea why in the first line they wrote `serial_header` while in the last line they wrote `serial_header_t`. I am wondering which one is the actual name of this struct and what does that `_t` added in the last line means?

Comment: This must have a zillion duplicates

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why should we typedef a struct so often in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252780/why-should-we-typedef-a-struct-so-often-in-c)

Comment: Yeah but the problem was I didn't now the word `typedef` before asking this question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) you can assume that serial_header_t  is equivalent to nx_struct serial_header, and because of that you can declare the variable in the program like
         serial_header_t  nx1;

NOTE: you do not need to use nx_struct serial_header.

2) In case you miss typedef and simple declare like the following way,

```
nx_struct serial_header {
  nx_am_addr_t dest;
  nx_am_addr_t src;
  nx_uint8_t length;
  nx_am_group_t group;
  nx_am_id_t type;
}
```

then,
   in the source code you should use like:

```
        nx_struct serial_header nx1;
```

Hope this helps.