# What the struct "zend_ptr_stack" means in Zend of PHP?

Tags: php

At line 29 of "Zend/zend_globals.h" in PHP-5.2.17.

What the struct "zend_ptr_stack" means and what's the use of this struct?

```
typedef struct _zend_ptr_stack {
    int top, max;
    void **elements;
    void **top_element;
} zend_ptr_stack;
```

Comment: did my post below answer your question?  If so, please "Accept" my answer. Accepting answers is an important part of the process, and the site keeps track of your 'Accept' ratio - If your ratio is too low, users will stop answering your questions.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which of these questions you are asking:

1. What is the `_zend_ptr_stack` struct used for?

   The `_zend_ptr_stack` struct is used, along with supporting code, to implement a `Stack` data type. See here for more information:

   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28abstract_data_type%29
2. What does the trailing `zend_ptr_stack` do?

   The trailing `zend_ptr_stack` declaration allows you to reference the `struct _zend_ptr_stack` without having to use the `struct` keyword.  See here for more information:

   [Why should we typedef a struct so often in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252780/why-should-we-typedef-a-struct-so-often-in-c)

Hope that helps.