# Declaring the various typedefs in a stack ADT

Tags: c, struct, abstract-data-type

Here's my problem: I need to implement a FIFO/LIFO list stack as ADT species 1. My program is modular and it have an `item.h` module:

```
    #ifndef ITEM_H_INCLUDED
    #define ITEM_H_INCLUDED

    typedef struct
    {
        char stringa[20];
        int numero;
    } Item;        
    #endif // ITEM_H_INCLUDED
```

The `head.h` module:

```
#ifndef HEAD_H_INCLUDED
#define HEAD_H_INCLUDED

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "item.h"  

void QUEUEinit();
int QUEUEempty();
void QUEUEput_top(Item);
void QUEUEput_bottom(Item);
Item QUEUEget_top();
Item QUEUEget_bottom();

#endif // HEAD_H_INCLUDED
```

The main.c and data.c; what i need is how i declare a `QEUEnode struct` and where.

Thank you for the help :)

Comment: I believe this post should answer your question.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252780/why-should-we-typedef-a-struct-so-often-in-c

Comment: more or less, but it does not deal with the pointers. What i need is to declare te pointer of the QUEUEnode in the header, and then define te structure in the data.c

Comment: So by "declare the pointers of the QUEUEnode" do you mean set up your functions to pass QUEUEnode pointers?

Comment: i'm sorry, i badly explained; what i need is how i declare a structure inside the module data.c, and his pointer in head.h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since none of your QUEUE* functions receive a `QUEUEnode *`, you can hide it in the head.c file, along with the `QUEUEnode root;` that they operate on.

If you want to use multiple queues, then it should probably be in the head.h file so they can be created in main.c. For this, you'll also need to modify the functions to accept a queue to operate on.