# Why is CGPoint declared twice?

Tags: c, struct, typedef

I'm learning about structures within structures and typedef definitions.  I understand normal typedef definitions, but in this example a typedef is used for struct data points

```
struct CGPoint{
    CGFloat x;
    CGFloat y;
};

typedef struct CGPoint CGPoint;

CGPoint rectPt;

rectPt.x=2;
rectPt.y=3;
```

I dont understand typedef struct CGPoint CGPoint; 
Why is CGPoint listed twice?

Comment: This might help answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612328/difference-between-struct-and-typedef-struct-in-c  This is not something specific to Objective-C but has to do with how the struct keyword works in C.

Comment: This one is also relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252780/why-should-we-typedef-a-struct-so-often-in-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you don't use

```
typedef struct CGPoint CGPoint;
```

you can't write

```
CGPoint rectPt;
```

but instead you have to write explicitly

```
struct CGPoint rectPt;
```

because in C defining a `struct` doesn't automatically define a typename for that as it happens in C++

Answer (score 1):

After `typedef` you can use `CGPoint` instead of  `struct CGPoint`.

A simpler way to achieve this is to combine them like this:

```
typedef struct CGPoint{
    CGFloat x;
    CGFloat y;
} CGPoint;
```