# Declaring a typedef for a function returning a struct pointer?

Tags: c, struct, typedef

This is an extract from a header I found in a 3rd party library:

```
struct aiFileIO;
struct aiFile;

// aiFile write callback
typedef size_t   (*aiFileWrite) (struct aiFile*, const char*);

// aiFileIO open callback
typedef aiFile* (*aiFileOpen)  (struct aiFileIO*, const char*);
```

Why does the last line not contain `struct` type specifier before the return type?
In other words why is this last line not:

```
typedef struct aiFile* (*aiFileOpen)  (struct aiFileIO*, const char*);
```

Which would make it clear that the function returns a pointer to a struct aiFile.

In case its important the `struct aiFile` is defined in the same header a couple of lines later.

Comment: Maybe because the header file was created to be used in a C++ project, where the `struct` keyword is not needed? Or maybe there's an `typedef` that you haven't seen?

Comment: I am 99% confident that this header is to be used from C. This is the file if you don't mind taking a look: https://github.com/assimp/assimp/blob/d6551990433264e029b476455db90d1d889e461c/include/assimp/cfileio.h

Comment: Then I suggest you report it to the author as a bug.

Comment: `extern "C"` is a typical C++ construct.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis do you mind elaborating a bit on your comment? I am not sure what does that imply.

Comment: `extern "C"` tells a C++ compiler that the following declarations are to be decorated in a C style, i.e. not the full C++ decoration. It is a typical C++ construct. See [this S.O. question and its answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041866/in-c-source-what-is-the-effect-of-extern-c).

Comment: What it means is that the header is meant to be used by a C++ compiler. The omission of `struct` seems to indicate the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only explanation I can think of is that the header was meant for C++, where you don't [need to `typedef` struct names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252780/why-should-we-typedef-a-struct-so-often-in-c).

If the header is designed to be used from C, then that's a bug since the code won't build as C.

Comment: This header is supposed to provide the c interface to a c++ library. Is this a bug then?   (this is the file: https://github.com/assimp/assimp/blob/d6551990433264e029b476455db90d1d889e461c/include/assimp/cfileio.h )

Comment: It does not build indeed! :) Although the lib compiled fine, but I guess that its because they don't use the file internally. Only as an interface.