# What's the difference between `typedef struct X { }` and `typedef struct { } X`?

Tags: c, struct, typedef

What's the difference between these two declarations in C:

```
typedef struct square{

   //Some fields

};
```

and

```
typedef struct{  

           //Some fields

} square;
```

Comment: I know, I have some fields in my struct, I just need to know the difference of the name on the bottom and top of the struct...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why should we typedef a struct so often in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252780/why-should-we-typedef-a-struct-so-often-in-c)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first declaration:

```
typedef struct square {
    // Some fields
};
```

defines a type named `struct square`. The `typedef` keyword is redundant (thanks to HolyBlackCat for pointing that out). It's equivalent to:

```
struct square {
   //Some fields
};
```

(The fact that you can use the `typedef` keyword in a declaration without defining a type name is a glitch in C's syntax.)

This first declaration probably *should* have been:

```
typedef struct square {
    // Some fields
} square;
```

The second declaration:

```
typedef struct {
    // Some fields
} square;
```

defines an anonymous `struct` type and then gives it the alias `square`.

Remember that `typedef` by itself doesn't define a new type, only a new name for an existing type. In this case the `typedef` and the (anonymous) `struct` definition happen to be combined into a single declaration.

Answer (score 2):

```
struct X { /* ... */ };
```

That create a new Type. So you can declare this new type by

```
struct X myvar = {...}
```

or

```
struct X *myvar = malloc(sizeof *myvar);
```

typdef is intended to name a type

```
typedef enum { false, true } boolean;
boolean b = true; /* Yeah, C ANSI doesn't provide false/true keyword */
```

So here, you renamed the enum to boolean.

So when you write

```
typedef struct X {
    //some field
} X;
```

You rename the type struct X to X. When i said rename, it's more an other name.

Tips, you can simply write :

```
typedef struct {
    //some field
} X;
```

But if you need a field with the same type (like in a linked list) you had to give a name to your struct

```
typedef struct X {
    X *next; /* will not work */
    struct X *next; /* ok */
} X;
```

Hope this helps :)

Edit :
As Keith Thompson said, typdef is intended to create alias :)