# Using malloc on variables created from typedef in a function

Tags: c, malloc

I want to create a new `intarr_t` with initial size `len`, but I've never handled this type of problem with a `typedef`'ed variable.

My problem is that `intarr_create()` should allocate the array space and then return a pointer to it if malloc was successful or a pointer to `NULL` if I failed. How can I fix this?

Also, why there is a * symbol in the function?

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int* data;
    unsigned int len;
} intarr_t;

intarr_t* intarr_create(unsigned int len) { 
    //intarr_t with initial size len
    intarr_t = (int *) malloc(len); // not working here, can someone explain why?
    if(intarr_t != NULL) {
        return intarr_t;
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }
}

int main() {
    int len = 15;
    int h = intarr_create(len);
    printf("%d\n", h);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that [`typedef`'ing structs](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4566358/1757964) is one of the worst and most horrid abuses of the C language. If you can avoid using it, please do so.

Comment: You are trying to assign a pointer type to a non-pointer type in your function call in `main`.  You may as well just return the result of `malloc` if you are going to return NULL on fail anyway, [and don't cast the result of `malloc`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: @APerson that's a bit extreme, it has some advantages and few drawbacks

Comment: @MattMcNabb Fair enough; but it causes enough maintainability headaches to be inadvisable in the long run.

Comment: @APerson I disagree based on experience. Namespace pollution problems can be avoided with good naming conventions. Naming a variable the same thing as its tag name is silly. YMMV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not working because you did not give your variable a name.  Also, `int*` and `intarr_t` are not the same type, so you will get a type mismatch unless you change the cast.

Comment: What do you mean by changing the cast?

Comment: @BeginnerC you wrote `(int*) malloc(len)`.  The `(int*)` is called a cast; it changes the type of the `malloc()` call from `void*` (a pointer to anything) to `int*` (a pointer to an integer variable).  But you don't have an integer variable, so you need to change it to something like `(intarr_t*)`.  You'll also need to make that variable into a pointer.  You'll end up with something like `intarr_t *result = (intarr_t*) malloc(len);`

Comment: Thank you for quick response, but I am slightly confused and forgive my slow understanding but since I want to return a pointer to the newly-allocated intarr_t If successful (i.e. memory allocation succeeds, would I be returning result?

Comment: Most likely.  You may not want to pass `len` to `malloc()` as-is, though.  The argument to `malloc()` should be a number of bytes.  You probably want to use `sizeof(intarr_t)` instead of a custom length.  I imagine you'll also want to allocate an array of integers and return it in `result->data`, which requires a separate `malloc()` call (something like `result->data = (int*) malloc(len*sizeof(int))`).

Comment: What kind of statement in my main should I be using if I want to store the return value? My main declaration of h being equal to it doens't seem to work.

Comment: `h` needs to be a pointer to `intarr_t`.  Right now, you've declared it as `int h`.  You need to change it to something like `intarr_t *h`.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite your function into this:

```
intarr_t* intarr_create(unsigned int len)
{ 
    intarr_t *result;

    result = (intarr_t *)malloc(sizeof(intarr_t));   // allocate memory for struct
    if(result != NULL)
    {
        result->data = (int *)malloc(len * sizeof(int));   // allocate memory for data
        result->len = len;
        if (result->data == NULL)
        {
           /* handle error */
        }
    }
    else
    {
        /* handle error */
    }

    return (result);
}
```

You have to do a "double" malloc to get it right. First you have to allocate the memory for the `intarr_t` and if that was successful you have to allocate the memory for the data array.

Additionally `malloc` returns a `void *` which must be cast to the correct pointer type (should be a warning or maybe even an error with some compilers).

Comment: This returns an array of intarr_t structs with no memory allocated for the data. I don't think this is what the OP wants.

Comment: @Daniel According to the question this is exactly what the function should do (`My problem is that intarr_create() should allocate the array space and then return a pointer to it if malloc was successful or a pointer to NULL if I failed.`)... ...huups sorry missed a bit!

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems with your `intarr_create` function. First of all, you need to name your `intarr_t` variable. Now you have the slightly trickier problem of allocating memory for the actual array of integers in addition to your intarr structure. Remember, that you will have to call delete *twice* to destroy this object. Once on the data, and once on the actual structure itself.

```
intarr_t* intarr_create(unsigned int len)
{
    intarr_t* array = (intarr_t*)malloc(sizeof(intarr_t));
    array->data = (int*)malloc(len * sizeof(int));

    return array;
}
```