# Interesting finding about using typedef for structures in C

Tags: struct, typedef

I've noticed something interesting. I want to make sure of it and discuss about it:

These two are not the same:

```
    typedef struct str_type structure
    struct str_type{
       int x;
       int y;
       unsigned int z;
       uint8_t ui;
    };
    //-----------------------
    typedef struct str_type{
       int x;
       int y;
       unsigned int z;
       uint8_t ui;
    } structure;
```

In the first case by writing `structure`, we actually write `struct str_type`.
In the second case by writing `structure`, we are actually writing a whole daclaration

```
    struct str_type{
       int x;
       int y;
       unsigned int z;
       uint8_t ui;
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why should we typedef a struct so often in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252780/why-should-we-typedef-a-struct-so-often-in-c)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between 'struct' and 'typedef struct' in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612328/difference-between-struct-and-typedef-struct-in-c)