# what is the difference between timespec and struct timespec?

Tags: c, time, timespec

I try to create a code for generating of timestamp. I found two different structures, but its not clear what is the difference? Can anybody help me to understand what is the difference between these two structures?  `struct timespec` and `timespec now`?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252780/why-should-we-typedef-a-struct-so-often-in-c

Comment: It doesnt answer my question.  If  I dont use struct  I schould write typedef struct. Is there a diference if I write struct timespec or  just timespec?

Comment: @check There's no such type as just `timespec`, so you can't use that in C code unless you've  created a typedef yourself . (Though if your code is C++, it's a different matter - `timespec` and `struct timespec` would be the same)

Answer (score 2):

The following structure:

```
struct timespec
```

is provided by the POSIX.1b standard, defined in time.h.  From the GNU libc documentation, [21.2 Elapsed Time](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Elapsed-Time.html):

> Data Type: struct timespec
>   The struct timespec structure represents an elapsed time. It is declared in time.h and has the following members:
>
> long int tv_sec
>   This represents the number of whole seconds of elapsed time.
>
> long int tv_nsec
>   This is the rest of the elapsed time (a fraction of a second), represented as the number of nanoseconds. It is always less than one billion.

If you saw the following:

```
timespec now
```

Someone probably wrote a typedef for the struct, and "now" would refer to a variable name.  If you wrote a typedef for the struct, there would be no difference between "struct timespec" and "timespec".

There are many functions in time.h that can help you.  You can find full documentation here: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/time.h.html