# storing data from a union into another variable

Tags: unions

I have some code that I'm trying to understand.  Is it possible to get 2,3,4 back after it's stored in long int bb?

When I print out bb, I get 772.  Is this a pointer value?

```
struct char_struct
{
   unsigned char x;
   unsigned char y;
   unsigned char z;

};
union longest
{
   unsigned long int aa;
   struct char_struct b;
};

int main()
{
   unsigned long int bb = 0;
   union longest Longest;
   Longest.b.x = 2;
   Longest.b.y = 3;
   Longest.b.x = 4;
   bb = Longest.aa;
   printf("%ld",bb);
   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Unions are a "one of the properties" not "all of the properties" (a struct). Do you mean to use a struct here (i.e. do you want to populate all properties at once or just one of them)? As it stands, `Longest.aa` is uninitialized when you assign it to `bb`.

Comment: yes all of them.

Answer (score 1):

Unions in C are offer a choice of multiple members, each of which is mapped to the same memory location. If you set more than one, you're corrupting the memory of the other members.

Beyond this, `Longest.aa` is uninitialized, so you're printing a garbage value.

It sounds like you'd like a struct, which offers a "vertical" collection of members that can all be set and accessed simultaneously (as you're doing with `char_struct`). The size of the struct is at least the sum of all of its member sizes plus any [cache size alignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment) the compiler adds.

Here's a sample program illustrating a few of these points:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct char_struct {
    unsigned char x;
    unsigned char y;
    unsigned char z;
};

struct longest_t {
    unsigned long int aa;
    struct char_struct b;
};

int main() {
    unsigned long int bb = 0;
    struct longest_t longest;
    longest.b.x = 2;
    longest.b.y = 3;
    longest.b.z = 4;
    longest.aa = 42;
    bb = longest.aa;
    printf("%ld\n", bb);
    printf("%d %d %d\n", longest.b.x, longest.b.y, longest.b.z);
    printf("longest_t size: %lu\n", sizeof(struct longest_t));
    printf("char_struct size: %lu\n", sizeof(struct char_struct));
    printf("ul int size: %lu\n", sizeof(unsigned long int));
    return 0;
}
```

A run on my machine shows:

```
42
2 3 4
longest_t size: 16
char_struct size: 3
ul int size: 8
```

You may wish to [typedef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252780/why-should-we-typedef-a-struct-so-often-in-c) your structs, and I suggest more semantically-meaningful variable names, although I do realize this is an example program. There are a few conventions for struct names, but typically variable names are not upper camel cased like `Longest`.

Comment: Thanks, it was used in someone's program.  I still don't understand why it was coded that way.