# i am new to structures i dont know what is causing the error : "duplicate identifiers"

Tags: c

I am writing a program that read two dates(type STRUCT) from the user and compares them using a function which be called in main{}

````
struct datum1 {
    short tag;
    short monat;
    int jahr; }datum1;
struct datum2 {
    short tag;
    short monat;
    int jahr; }datum2;
void datumvergleich (struct datum1,struct datum2);

int main(){
    printf("Geben Sie den Ersten Datum im Tag Monat und Jahr");
    scanf("%hd\n",& datum1.tag);
    scanf("%hd\n",& datum1.monat); 
    scanf("%d\n",& datum1.jahr);  
    datumvergleich (datum1,datum2);
        }
/* void datumvergleich (struct d1, struct d2 )*/{ 
    int t,m,j;
    j=d1.jahr-d2.jahr;
    m=d1.monat-d2.monat;
    t=d1.tag-d2.tag;``` ...
i keep getting "error duplicate identifier:" at the line where there is the comment bracket " /* */ "
just FYI tag/monat/jahr mean day/month/year in german.
thanks in advance
````

Answer (score 0):

The commented line needs to be

```
void datumvergleich (struct datum1 d1, struct datum2 d2 )
```

in order to match the function prototype further up in the program (you don't need to specify the variable names in function prototypes, just the types). Note that if `datum1` and `datum2` will always have exactly the same members, then you could use the same `struct` for both `d1` and `d2`.

Note that you can use `typedef` to obviate the tedium of writing `struct datum1` etc. See [Why should we typedef a struct so often in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252780/why-should-we-typedef-a-struct-so-often-in-c)