# Compilation error in function declaration in C

Tags: c, function, structure, declaration, function-declaration

I am getting errors during the compilation of this C program and is related to the declaration of the function. What is the problem here? When I declare `void display(student);` it shows a warning but if I change to `void display(struct student st)` it shows some errors.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void display(student);
void read_student(student);
struct student{
    int roll;
    char name[20],depart[20],sex,result;

    float percent,marks[5],total; 

};

void main(){
    int n;
    printf("enter the no of data you want to enter ??");
    scanf("%d",&n);

     struct student s[n];
     for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        read_student(&s[i]);
        printf("\n---------------------------------------------------Result Sheet --------------------------------------------------------------------");
        printf("\nRoll No.\tName\t\tSex\tDepartment\t\tMarks\t\t\t\tTotal\tPercentage\tResult ");
    printf("\n----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    printf("\n                              \t\t\t\tA\tB\tC\tD\tE\n");
    printf("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");

     for(int i=0;i<n;i++)  
        display(s[i]);


}
 void display(struct student st){


    printf("\n%2d\t%10s\t\t%c\t%10s\t%.2f\t%.2f\t%.2f\t%.2f\t%.2f\t%4.2f\t  %2.2f\t\t%c\n",st.roll,st.name,st.sex,st.depart,st.marks[0],st.marks[1],st.marks[2],st.marks[3],st.marks[4],st.total,st.percent,st.result);


}
 void read_student(struct student *std){
     int c=0,i;
    printf("Enter the roll no:");
    scanf("%d",&std->roll);
     printf("enter the name:\n");
     scanf("%s",std->name);
     printf("enter Sex:\n");
     scanf(" %c",&std->sex);
     printf("Enter the department:\n");
     scanf("%s",std->depart);
     printf("enter the marks in 5 subjects:\n");
     for(i=0;i<5;i++){
      scanf("%f",&std->marks[i]);
      std->total=std->total+std->marks[i];
      if(std->marks[i]>=40)
      c++;
     }
      if(c==5)
      std->result='p';
      else
        std->result='f';



     std->percent=(std->total/500)*100;


}
```

Comment: The compiler reads your code from top to bottom. So at the point where you declare the functions, it has no idea what `student` means, because you haven't told it yet.

Comment: BTW, the best way to solve this problem is to put `main` at the end of the file. Then you don't need the function declarations at all.

Comment: `void main()` is not a valid signature for `main()` in Standard C: `void main()` --> `int main(void)`. Curious: why pass an entire copy of the `student` structure to the `display_student()` function when you could just pass a pointer to `struct student`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler needs to know what `struct student` is, when using it elsewhere in the code, for example declaring a function with it as type of an argument/parameter. The compiler reads the source file from top to bottom. You need to declare the structure before you use it as a type in the declaration of a function:

```
struct student;   // forward declaration of structure `student`.

void display(struct student);       // ok, because `struct student` is declared before.
void read_student(struct student*); // ok, because `struct student` is declared before.

struct student{                     // definition of structure `student`.
    int roll;
    char name[20],depart[20],sex,result;
    float percent,marks[5],total; 
};
```

Alternatively, you can define the structure before the declarations of the functions:

```
struct student{    // define the structure `student` before the function declarations.
    int roll;
    char name[20],depart[20],sex,result;
    float percent,marks[5],total; 
};

void display(struct student);
void read_student(struct student*);
```

Another way would be to put the definitions of the functions `read_student` and `display` before `main()`, but after the the definition of the structure `student`. In this way you can omit the separate declarations of the functions `read_student` and `display` and of course the forward declaration of the structure `student` as well:

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct student{
    int roll;
    char name[20],depart[20],sex,result;
    float percent,marks[5],total; 
};

void read_student(struct student *std){
     int c=0,i;
     printf("Enter the roll no:");
     scanf("%d",&std->roll);
     printf("enter the name:\n");
     scanf("%s",std->name);
     printf("enter Sex:\n");
     scanf(" %c",&std->sex);
     printf("Enter the department:\n");
     scanf("%s",std->depart);
     printf("enter the marks in 5 subjects:\n");
     for(i=0;i<5;i++){
      scanf("%f",&std->marks[i]);
      std->total=std->total+std->marks[i];
      if(std->marks[i]>=40)
      c++;
     }
      if(c==5)
      std->result='p';
      else
        std->result='f';

     std->percent=(std->total/500)*100;
}

void display(struct student st){
    printf("\n%2d\t%10s\t\t%c\t%10s\t%.2f\t%.2f\t%.2f\t%.2f\t%.2f\t%4.2f\t  %2.2f\t\t%c\n",st.roll,st.name,st.sex,st.depart,st.marks[0],st.marks[1],st.marks[2],st.marks[3],st.marks[4],st.total,st.percent,st.result);
}

int main(){
    int n;
    printf("enter the no of data you want to enter ??");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    struct student s[n];

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        read_student(&s[i]);

    printf("\n---------------------------------------------------Result Sheet --------------------------------------------------------------------");
    printf("\nRoll No.\tName\t\tSex\tDepartment\t\tMarks\t\t\t\tTotal\tPercentage\tResult ");
    printf("\n----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    printf("\n                              \t\t\t\tA\tB\tC\tD\tE\n");
    printf("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)  
        display(s[i]);
}
```

---

At the declaration of functions you can omit identifiers of parameters, but not the type of parameters.

It is also not permissible to use the structure `student` without preceding the `struct` keyword as you tried it with:

```
void display(student);
```

since you use the structure `student` by its definition:

```
struct student{
...
};
```

If you would use a `typedef` like for example:

```
typedef struct student{
...
} student;
```

You could omit the `struct` keyword, but if you use a `typedef` or just use the structure as it is, is a kind of controversy topic amongst the community with regards to readibility. All references to that, you can see on the answers to these questions:

[typedef struct vs struct definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675351/typedef-struct-vs-struct-definitions/26389105#26389105)

[Why should we typedef a struct so often in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252780/why-should-we-typedef-a-struct-so-often-in-c)

I personally recommend to keep on using the `struct` variant, even if it requires a little bit more typing with the keys, but makes your code a little bit clearer.