# Questions about Structure definitions

Tags: c, struct, declaration, typedef

I am new to c, I have a question about structures (see the next code):

```
typedef struct student{
  char name[20];
  int grade;
} student1;

typedef struct group_project{
  char name_of_group[20];
  struct group_project *next;  // points to the next group
  student1 *student1;           //head of the group
} group_project;
```

1. What is the difference between student and student1 (what is the name of the struct?). 
   Can you use the same name?
2. Why do you need to add "struct" when using group_project but you dont add struct when using the student struct?
3. Can you use a structure without "typedef"?

Comment: 1. first one is the name of the type, second one is the variable name. yes. 2. because it's not typedef'd yet. 3. yes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675351/typedef-struct-vs-struct-definitions

Comment: Note that the first typedef specifies the name `student1` (with a digit); the type `student` in the second struct is not the same type — it isn't clear what type it is, but it isn't the `struct student` type based on the info in the question.  This might just be a typo in the question — if so, please fix it.

Answer (score 3):

`student1` is an alias for the type `struct student`.

And inside the `group_project` structure the type-alias `group_project` doesn't exist yet, so you have to use `struct group_project`.

And in C you can't use the structure tag name (like e.g. `student`) without the keyword `struct`. The whole type is `struct student`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, so basicaly the compiler replaces "student1" with "struct student"? is it ok to just give them the same name (like in group_project?)

Comment: @mark Something like that. And it's okay to use the same structure tag name and type-alias name.

Comment: @mark "*so basically the compiler replaces "student1" with "struct student"?*" Yes, but only if `student1` is a `typedef` alias as you did it in the example in the question. If you only define `student1` by f.e.: `struct student{...}student1` then you can´t, since `student1` is then an object of the structure itself. "*is it ok to just give them the same name (like in group_project?)*" - Yes, they reside in different name spaces.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the difference between `student` and `student1` (what is the name of the struct?). Can you use the same name?

`student` is the structure *tag* or the "name" of the structure itself and `student1` is an `typedef`d *alias* of type `struct student`. Yes, they can have the same name or *identifier* because they reside in different name spaces.

> Why do you need to add "`struct`" when using `group_project` but you don´t add `struct` when using the `student1` structure?

In C, as opposed to C++, when you define an object of a structure, and didn´t `typedef`d the structure or defined the object at the declaration of the structure itself, you have to precede the structure tag by the keyword `struct` at the declaration of the respective object, like for example:

```
struct student student_x;         // `struct` keyword required.
```

Since `student1` is already `typedef`d before, at the declaration of the structure `student`, you don´t need to use the `struct` keyword anymore, when you defining an object of that structure type.

As opposed to that, `group_project` as type of the pointer `next` in the `project_group` structure needs to be preceded by the keyword `struct` because the `typedef` of `group_project` is defined thereafter in the source code and isn´t valid at this point of time inside the structure.

> Can you use a structure without "`typedef`"?

Yes, of course. Some user amongst the community even say this is even more appreciated because it makes your code more readable. I recommend to always use the structure by itself and not blending with any `typedef`, even if it requires a little bit more key typing, just to keep your code a little bit clearer, but this is a matter of opinion and style. Here you can make you your own image of it:

[typedef struct vs struct definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675351/typedef-struct-vs-struct-definitions)

[Why should we typedef a struct so often in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252780/why-should-we-typedef-a-struct-so-often-in-c)