# Incompatible struct pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers

So I'm having this error:

```c
.\linkedbank.c: In function 'enqueue':
.\linkedbank.c:48:17: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   q->rear->next = temp;
```

Which is weird, because im sure temp is the same exact type as q->rear->next. Am I missing something?
this is the code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//=============STRUCTS=============//
typedef struct{
    int data;
    struct node* next;
}node;

typedef struct{
    node* front;
    node* rear;
}queue;
//============PRIMITIVE FUNCS======//
void enqueue(queue* q, int x);
int dequeue(queue* q);
//====Utility Funcs//
queue* createQueue();
void destroyQueue();
int isEmpty(queue* q); //Cannot get full! and O(1) runtime!!!
void displayQueue(queue* q);

//============ FUNCTION DEFINITIONS =====//
void enqueue(queue* q, int x)
{
    node* temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    temp->data = x;
    temp->next = NULL;
    if(isEmpty(q))
    {
        q->front = q->rear = temp;  
    }else
    {
        q->rear->next = temp;
        q->rear = temp;
    }
}

int dequeue(queue* q)
{
    node* temp = q->front;
    if(isEmpty(q))
    {   
        fprintf(stderr, "CANNOT DEQUEUE EMPTY QUEUE");
        return -1;
    }else if(q->front == q->rear)
    {
        q->front = q->rear = NULL;
    }else
    {
        q->front = q->front->next;
    }
    return temp->data;      
    free(temp);
}

int isEmpty(queue* q){
    return (q->front->next == NULL && q->rear->next == NULL);
}
```

So as you can see q->rear and q->front are both (node*), and temp is also (node*) how are these incompatible if they're the same type?
Im so confused, please help.

Answer (score 2):

```
typedef struct{
    int data;
    struct node* next;
}node;
```

This defines an anonymous struct type and defines `node` as a name for that type.  However, you have not defined any type called `struct node`.  The compiler thus understands it as being some opaque type, unrelated to `node`, that you are defining pointers to.

You probably meant to write `typedef struct node { ... } node;` so that the struct you've defined is called `struct node` and `node` is typedef'd as another name for that type.

For more information, see

[typedef struct vs struct definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675351/typedef-struct-vs-struct-definitions?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Why should we typedef a struct so often in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252780/why-should-we-typedef-a-struct-so-often-in-c)