# Why do i get this Invalid read size of 8

Tags: c, linked-list, valgrind

why do I get an `Invalid read of size 8`

My goal is to pass an array of integers to a function that will return a pointer to the last `Item` in the linked list and it will fill the array of `Item` pointers with pointers for each item created

everything works fine and compiling does not show any errors and running the program does not show any errors as well but when I use `valgrind` with it I get the error in valgrind output below

```
typedef struct Item
{
    int num ;   
    struct Item *next;  
}Item;


Item * create_list(int * arr, int len, Item ** lst)
{
    Item * tmpItem = malloc(sizeof(Item));

    for (int i=0; i < len; i++)
    {
        lst[i] = tmpItem;
        tmpItem->num = arr[i];
        if ( i+1!=len )
        {
            tmpItem->next = malloc(sizeof(Item));
            tmpItem = tmpItem->next;
        }
        else
            tmpItem->next = NULL;
    }
    return tmpItem;
}



void free_lst(Item ** lst, int len)
{
    for (int i =0; i < len; i++)
    {
        free(lst[i]);
    }
}
int main()
{
    int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    Item * items[sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int)];
    Item * tmp = create_list(arr, sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int), items);
    free_lst(items, sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int));
    printf('%p\n',tmp->next);

}
```

valgrind output

```
==12169== Invalid read of size 8
==12169==    at 0x109270: main (main.c:26)
==12169==  Address 0x4a59228 is 8 bytes inside a block of size 16 free'd
==12169==    at 0x483CA3F: free (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==12169==    by 0x10939D: free_lst (list.c:45)
==12169==    by 0x10926B: main (main.c:24)
==12169==  Block was alloc'd at
==12169==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==12169==    by 0x10931C: create_list (list.c:24)
==12169==    by 0x109209: main (main.c:13)
==12169==
```

I don't understand why am I getting this error but I guess this is because the last element in the linked list has a null pointer and this causes the last element to be 8 bytes long not 16

Comment: Why do you think the size of a null pointer is different from any other pointer?

Comment: You should rethink your creation loop. The `if ( i+1!=len )` should not be necessary, you have an equivalent condition in the `for` loop. You just need to rearrange the order of things a bit.

Comment: The error doesn't say that the size is invalid. It's saying that the data being read is invalid (uninitialized), and its size happens to be 8 bytes.

Comment: You are mixing a linked-list with an array?

Comment: @Neil i am trying to convert an array to a linked list

Comment: @EugeneSh. can you explain this more in an answer with a code snippet, please

Comment: @Barmar I assumed it would be different

Comment: That makes no sense. The size is the size of the pointer variable, it has to be able to hold either null or non-null pointers.

Comment: Fyi, change `int *next;` in the structure to `struct Item *next;`, which is what it should be in the first place.

Comment: @WhozCraig can you explain why should I do so

Comment: Because an `int` is not `struct Item`, would be reason enough for me (and your code).

Comment: I don't see how this code can possibly create this error, since you don't touch the items after freeing them

Comment: Always enable and heed your compiler's warnings (e.g. using `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` using gcc). Should be `struct Item { int num; struct Item *next; }; typedef struct Item Item;`. Do you still have the problem after fixing this (which I think results in undefined behaviour)?

Comment: @ikegami I did `gcc -Wall -pedantic -ggdb3` and this does not show any warnings or errors

Comment: Are you sure you are compiling the same code you posted here?  Every version of gcc I tried gives `warning: assignment to 'Item *' from incompatible pointer type 'int *'`, as it rightly should (that is the issue that WhozCraig noted above).  https://godbolt.org/z/WEvYqW7sr

Comment: I also cannot reproduce any valgrind error with your code.  Again, are you sure it is exactly the same version you are compiling and testing?  (In fact it can't be *exactly* the same because you are missing `#include <stdlib.h>` which should produce a ton of warnings.)

Comment: @KGBGUY You're assigning to a `int *` from a `Item *`. There's no compiler in existence that won't warn you about that major error. Noteably, gcc does warn contrary to your claim

Comment: As far as I understand the problem was in the `printf` line in the main function, it is printing the address of a null pointer and this causes the error to appear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Some problems

One is missing required headers.

```
typedef struct Item
```

See [discussion of typedef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252780/why-should-we-typedef-a-struct-so-often-in-c).

```
Item * create_list(int * arr, int len, Item ** lst)
```

The first two arguments are necessary, but the last one is unused. In the function itself, one forward declares the pointer in a manner that is confusing and will not work for a null list. This could be simplified.

```
void free_lst(struct Item ** lst, int len)
```

This frees a list as an array. This doesn't make sense since one is converting it to a linked-list.

```
int main()
```

See [What's the correct declaration of main()?](http://c-faq.com/ansi/maindecl.html).

```
Item * items[sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int)];
```

Why do you need an [array of pointer to Item](https://cdecl.org/?q=struct+Item+*+items%5B%5D)?

```
free_lst(items, sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int));
```

One is freeing the array of elements that haven't been initialized. I think you are seeing this behaviour from `valgrind` because `free` is being called on uninitialized memory.

```
printf('%p\n',tmp->next);
```

See [when should I use single quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683602/single-quotes-vs-double-quotes-in-c-or-c)? One assumes that the list is not empty and prints the second element?

### Intent

One is trying to *push* an item on the linked-list, an operation that is efficient, but the code is unnecessarily complex. Also, when one pushes a dynamically allocated object, it makes sense to *pop* to free the object. I've modified one's code with error checking (assuming POSIX-like compliance) and the changes listed above.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct Item
{
    int num ;
    struct Item *next;
};

int main(void)
{
    int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    struct Item * head = 0, *cursor;
    /* `size_t` stddef, included by stdlib and stdio */
    size_t i = sizeof arr / sizeof *arr;
    int success = EXIT_SUCCESS; /* stdlib */
    while(i) { /* Push backwards. */
        struct Item *tmp;
        if(!(tmp = malloc(sizeof *tmp))) goto catch; /* stdlib */
        tmp->num = arr[--i];
        tmp->next = head;
        head = tmp;
    }
    for(cursor = head; cursor; cursor = cursor->next)
        printf("%d\n", cursor->num); /* stdio */
    goto finally;
catch:
    success = EXIT_FAILURE; /* stdlib */
    perror("to list"); /* stdio */
finally:
    while(head) { /* Pop off linked-list. */
        struct Item *const prev = head;
        head = head->next;
        free(prev); /* stdlib */
    }
    return success;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Two main bugs here:

1. `printf('%p'...` instead of `printf("%p"...`
2. You try to `printf()` `tmp->next` after you've already freed it in `free_lst()`. Meaning that you've already freed this heap block, but you're still trying to read from it. And that's why valgrind throws an error.