# Instantiating a struct in C and initializing an array member of the struct

Tags: c, struct, initialization

I want to define a `struct` to emulate a vector, containing an array of double `vec` and an integer `N` representing how many entries are valid.

I want to set all the entries of the array to be zero before filling N of them with non zero values. I tried this code:

```
typedef struct {
  int N;
  double vec[1000];
} Vector ;

int main()
{
  int N1;
  double vec1[1000] = { 0 };
  Vector vector;
  vector.vec = { 0 };
  return 0;
}
```

The compiler accepts the initialization of `vec1`, but not of `vector.vec`. I get an error that says:

```
so.c:11:16: error: expected expression
  vector.vec = { 0 };
               ^
1 error generated.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The error message shown does not match the code. Please make a proper [mre]. Also: just because you called your struct `Vector` doesn't make it a vector, or a question that should be tagged that way, or a word that helps explain the question in the title; and the issues here aren't because of `typedef`, but instead are entirely related to using the `struct`.

Comment: I updated the code sorry about that

Comment: @user17732522 the question is tagged [c] and the code is intended to be written in C as far as I can tell.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Oops. I think I got confused by the `vector`.

Comment: Yes I want to define a typedef or a struct in C (not C++)

Comment: You can only initialize an array with `{...}` in the same statement where it is defined and not in a separate statement. I.e. `int a[3]={...};`, but `int a[3]; a={...};` is not.

Comment: thank you @wohlstad. So what would be the code?

Comment: Instead, try `Vector vector = { 0 };`

Comment: "I want to define a typedef or a struct " It's important to understand how the `typedef struct` idiom works in C. Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252780

Comment: For your `Vector` you can do as suggested above by @WeatherVane. But in general if you want to initialize as array you already declared, you need to assign the elements in a loop.

Comment: You can also zero a block of memory with `memset()`. Such as `memset(vector.vec, 0, sizeof vector.vec);`

Comment: As for the question, it is plainly a duplicate: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/330793 for the reference canonical. (I already voted to close as needing debugging details before that was fixed, so now I can't formally propose the duplicate.)

Comment: Like @WeatherVane suggested, `Vector vector = { 0 };` or `Vector vector = {.N = 0 };` if you want to be explicit about it. `Vector vector = { 0, {fill some} };` would also work. If the elements are not contiguous from the start: `Vector vector = {0, {[1] = 3.141, [3] = 6.6}};` etc.

Comment: Thank you @WeatherVane and wohlstad and Ted Lyngmo for your very helpful comments! :)

Comment: Presumably `vector.N` holds the number of elements so it isn't clear why you would want to do that.